# Access Denied Error while trying to get the client process executable path

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, winapi, namedpipeserverstream

I am working on a WCF service that is hosted as a windows service which uses named pipes - **NamedPipeServerStream** (Users privilege) to establish secured connection between server and client processes. To check the authenticity of the client process, I need to verify the digital signature of the client process executable and so I am trying to get the executable path of the client by using its process id.

I use **Windows 7 Professional SP1 (64 bit) OS** and **Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition** for developement. Both the server (windows service) and client processes (other exe) are built in **Release x64** mode only.

When some client process is connected to the server, I am trying to get the client process exe path but it is throwing **"Access Denied" error** in the following line of code:

**`return Process.GetProcessById(processId).MainModule.FileName;`**

Hence to resolve this issue, I had googled around and tried some other experimental trials as described below that too does not seem to work out.

**Experimental Trials**

1. Tried to get the client process handle with query access privilege but failed --> Always returns 0 and last Win32 error as 5 (**Access Denied**)

**`OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, processId);`**

2. Tried to get the client process handle with limited query access privilege but failed --> Always returns 0 and last Win32 error as 5 (**Access Denied**)

**`OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, processId);`**

3. Set the SeDebugPrivilege and proceeded to get the client process handle with limited query privilege but failed --> SeDebugPrivilege is enabled but still returning 0 for process handle and last Win32 error as 5 (**Access Denied**).
4. Tried to set administrator privilege to the windows service using app.manifest file (requireAdministrator attribute) but failed --> **Access denied**
5. Tried using ManagementObject to get the process info properties but failed --> Object reference not set to an instance of the object
6. Changed the logon account for the windows service as "Local System" from "Local Service" but failed

However, I tried all the above methods in a sample windows console application which is working fine without any errors and the same is not working in the windows service. Also I tried to convert the console application into a dll and referred it in the server to get the client process info but failed --> again Access denied

I am completely clueless about what is happening and how to resolve it. Your suggestions would be really helpful.

**EDIT :** Please find the code snippet for OpenProcess and the ProcessAccessFlags as below:

```
public static string GetProcessExecutablePath(int processId)
{
    try
    {
        string exePath = string.Empty;
        //If running on Vista or later use the new function
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
        {
            return GetProcessExecutablePathAboveVista(processId);
        }
        return Process.GetProcessById(processId).MainModule.FileName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Exception in GetProcessExecutablePath(): " + ex.Message + ": " + ex.InnerException;
    }
}    

private static string GetProcessExecutablePathAboveVista(int processId)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder(1024);
    IntPtr hprocess = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(NativeMethods.ProcessAccessFlags.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,
                                      false, processId);
    if (hprocess != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        try
        {
            int size = buffer.Capacity;
            if (NativeMethods.QueryFullProcessImageName(hprocess, 0, buffer, out size))
            {
                return buffer.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "Failed in QueryFullProcessImageName(): " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Exception in: " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            NativeMethods.CloseHandle(hprocess);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "Handle is Zero: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }
}
```

**NativeMethods.cs**

```
[Flags]
public enum ProcessAccessFlags
{
    PROCESS_TERMINATE = 0x0001,
    PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002,
    PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008,
    PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010,
    PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020,
    PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE = 0x0040,
    PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS = 0x0080,
    PROCESS_SET_QUOTA = 0x0100,
    PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION = 0x0200,
    PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400,
    PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME = 0x0800,
    PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = 0x1000,
    SYNCHRONIZE = 0x100000,
    DELETE = 0x00010000,
    READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000,
    WRITE_DAC = 0x00040000,
    WRITE_OWNER = 0x00080000,
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,
    PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | 0xFFFF
}

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenProcess", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "QueryFullProcessImageName", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName(IntPtr hprocess, int dwFlags, StringBuilder lpExeName, out int size);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CloseHandle", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);
```

Comment: Perhaps share the OpenProcess() code you tried and the values for the consts.  Add SetLastError=true to the DLLImport attribute for OpenProcess then look at the value of Marshal.GetLastWin32Error when it returns 0 to see if its also access-denied (5)

Comment: If you didn't already read, this can help you: http://www.aboutmycode.com/net-framework/how-to-get-elevated-process-path-in-net/

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for the response. I had edited the question to add the code snippet that I had tried for everyone's reference. Yes I had tried getting the last Win32 error and it returns 5 (Access Denied).

Comment: @RicardoPontual Thanks for the link. I had already gone through that and used the same in my code.

Comment: How have you verified that your service has the `SeDebugPrivilege`? Also, have you verified that the service obtains the correct process ID?

Comment: @YSK yes I had explicitly tried to enable SeDebugPrivilege from the code and proceed but it didn't work out. The process id is correct and verified that.

Comment: @SophiaS, For Windows starting from Vista to get process image file name by pid you may use `NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, ...)` to obtain array of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` structures for each process. This structure has `PVOID UniqueProcessId` to find pid you're looking for and `UNICODE_STRING ImageName` to get image file name, see 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724509(v=vs.85).aspx
https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/api/ex/sysinfo/process.htm

Answer (score 0):

For Windows starting from Vista to get process image file name by pid you may use `NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, ...)` to obtain array of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` structures for each process. This structure has `PVOID UniqueProcessId` to find pid you're looking for and `UNICODE_STRING ImageName` to get image file name, see 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724509(v=vs.85).aspx
https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/api/ex/sysinfo/process.htm